# Came across a javascript code, which I can't read

Tags: javascript

I came across this java script code and I don't know how I encode it. Here is a part of it:

```
var _0x6ah4=['a22uo1w=','a2VlcC1h2ZQ==','YMA0aG9y8XVlML==','Z3cCwgZGVmHBbG0ZQ==','Qk1OQ04=','enNHYAM=','P0ASTmI=','RkVPOE9=','Y2AQUEc=']
```

Can somebody tell me how to convert this into readable code?

Comment: I can read it. Its an array of strings with encoded values of some kind. Now if you want to decode those values, I don't think that is possible because nobody knows how they were encoded in the first place. Try https://www.base64decode.org/

Comment: It's just an array of strings. What it's used for I can't guess without context though

Comment: Yeah, this is valid javascript. An array of strings. Whats the problem here? How are we supposed to know what the string values represent?

Comment: It’s probably from an obfuscated file, designed to be as difficult as possible to reverse engineer. Not impossible of course, since the interpreter can still figure out what’s going on :p

Answer (score 1):

```
var _0x6ah4=['a22uo1w=','a2VlcC1h2ZQ==','YMA0aG9y8XVlML==','Z3cCwgZGVmHBbG0ZQ==','Qk1OQ04=','enNHYAM=','P0ASTmI=','RkVPOE9=','Y2AQUEc=']
```

Its simple.
variable name _0x6ah4 ,
its an array containing 9 elements.

You can fetch the data using foreach, if you want.

```
var _0x6ah4=['a22uo1w=','a2VlcC1h2ZQ==','YMA0aG9y8XVlML==','Z3cCwgZGVmHBbG0ZQ==','Qk1OQ04=','enNHYAM=','P0ASTmI=','RkVPOE9=','Y2AQUEc='];
for (var line=1; line<_0x6ah4.length; line++) {
   console.log(_0x6ah4[line]);
   //if you need to decode , do it here 
}
```